# cdk drag drop swap behavior swapping list

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

Here is a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krpro1) I have created.

The newly entered element will get swapped with the element in front. Works quite good.

The desired behavior would be:
**when dragging `b1` over `a1`, that a1 disappears from `list a` and gets previewed in `list b` at the position where `b1` was.**

How can I get the thing to work with better user experience? When looking at the source code of the cdk-dnd on GitHub this really is above me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what will work:

```
transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
transferArrayItem(event.container.data, event.previousContainer.data,
          event.currentIndex+1, event.previousIndex);
```

Please carefully look at code and you will understand it. It's all about index of 2 lists for swapping.